# How to draw the shape shown in the below image using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, tikz-node, tikz-pic

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, xllsnames, svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes, positioning}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{transparent}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\fill[fill=gray!40]([xshift=0mm, yshift=-10mm]current page.north west)rectangle([xshift=-100mm, yshift=-30mm]current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `signal` node shape.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, signal, signal to=east, minimum height=2cm, minimum width=8cm] at (0,0) {Optional Text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!